# python grep multiple words in logcat

Tags: python, logcat

**Shell script:**

```
logcat | grep -E "one|two|three"
```

**Python Code:**

```
key_words = [ "one", "two", "three"]
log_lines = os.popen("logcat");

for log_line in log_lines:
   for keyword in key_words:
        if keyword in log_line:
             print log_line
```

Is there any optimizations to above python code?

Comment: If a line contains multiple keywords, do you want it to print twice/thrice?

Comment: logcat can directly do [`logcat -e <regex>`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat), not sure it supports extended regex syntax like `|`. Also a line with multiple matches would only get shown once.

Comment: `os.popen()` used to come with a big fat ugly warning saying it's deprecated, but it looks like the warning is now gone.  I guess they couldn't kill it so they reimplemented it on top of `subprocess` which is what I was going to recommend instead.

Comment: If you are using Python 2, `os.popen()` is still very much a thing you should avoid. (But then Python 2 is now a thing you should very much avoid. Think about migrating to Python 3 ASAP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To emulate the exact pattern in your `grep` command, do

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(key_words))

for log_line in log_lines:
    if pattern.search(log_line):
        print log_line
```

If you want to allow special characters, you'll have to escape them:

```
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in key_words))
```

As you can imagine, using regex is a bit overkill in this case. Instead, you can do a direct search. You can use `any` to help with the search, since it short circuits.

```
for log_line in log_lines:
    if any(word in log_line for word in key_words):
        print log_line
```

This performs a linear search of the entire line for each keyword. You can make that a bit more efficient if the keywords are intended to be actual words, especially since you already have a set for the keywords:

```
for log_line in log_lines:
    if keywords.intersection(set(log_line.split()):
        print log_line
```

Comment: `any` is always underestimated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution prints lines that have multiple keywords as often as the number of keywords they have, that may be something you want to avoid. Also, if a keyword appears as part of another word, it also appears (although that matches the grep behaviour).

Some solutions:

```
import os

key_words = {"one", "two", "three"}
log_lines = ['This has a one and a two', 'Some ones', 'This one has neither, oh it does', 'This does not', 'A three']

# fixing the repetition    
for log_line in log_lines:
   for keyword in key_words:
        if keyword in log_line:
             print(log_line)
             break

# fixing the repetition and partial matches
for log_line in log_lines:
    for word in log_line.split():
        if word in key_words:
            print(log_line)
            break

# single line solution
print([log_line for log_line in log_lines if key_words & set(log_line.split()) != set()])

# single line solution with partial matches
print([log_line for log_line in log_lines if any(key_word in log_line for key_word in key_words)])
```

Comment: Note that key_words is a set in my examples, not a list, hence the `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the regular expression and try this scenario. You can also change regular expression as per your requirements check below example:

```
import re

key_words = [ "one", "two", "three"]
regex  = "|".join(key_words)
log_lines = open("logcat", 'r')
lines = log_lines.readlines()
print filter(lambda x : re.search(regex,x), lines)

log_lines.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

One first optimization would be to actually `break` as soon as you found one match:

```
key_words = [ "one", "two", "three"]
log_lines = os.popen("logcat");

for log_line in log_lines:
    for keyword in key_words:
        if keyword in log_line:
            print log_line
            break    # stop looking for keywords if you already found one
```

A more readable solution is to replace that keyword loop check with a regular expression. If there's a match, then print the line:

```
import re
key_words = [ "one", "two", "three"]
regex = re.compile('|'.join(key_words))    # one|two|three

log_lines = os.popen("logcat");
for log_line in log_lines:
    if regex.match(log_line):    # returns None if no match, an object if there is a match
        print log_line
```

From a performance standpoint, not sure which would be faster, but one is more readable. There are some caveats in results, though.

Comment: I'm sure you have seen the big warning box in the `os.popen` documentation which says do not use this?

Comment: @tripleee Yes, but it's what the OP has in their code, and it's not really part of the question. Could you actually comment this on the main question? I think it's important.

Comment: Oh, looks like the big bad warning is actually gone in Python 3.7. It is now reimplemented using `subprocess.Popen`. My bad.

Comment: It still is a bad warning for Python 2.7, so your point is valid, especially because I think this example is in Python 2.x. Thanks for checking!